# Java Applet Output File

Tags: java, file-io, applet, outputstream, japplet

I am trying to create a Java Applet that outputs information to a text file located in the same directory as the java applet. I understand Java Applets are not ideal, but I have spent a great deal of time on this and if possible want to solve this through applets. Here is some of my code on how I could read code from a file into a text box. I assume it would be something similar to this, but outputted.

```
public void readFile() {
  String line;
  URL url = null;
  try {
     url = new URL(getCodeBase(), fileToRead);
  }
  catch(MalformedURLException e) {
  }
  try {
     InputStream in = url.openStream();
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader
     (new InputStreamReader(in));
     strBuff = new StringBuffer();
     while((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
        strBuff.append(line + "\n");
     }
     a1.append("File Name : " + fileToRead + "\n");
     a1.append(strBuff.toString());
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial on how to write a text file?  Have you searched?  I'm sure there are many available.

Comment: Yes, But I have searched and Java Applets have a problem with security issues

Answer (score 0):

If you want an applet to store data on the local machine, from 6u10 the `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService` is available.

or on your local machine...

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "yourfile.txt");
```

---

You **must** have it signed, otherwise...

Keep in mind that from an Applet, you cannot directly write to the server's file system. You can issue a request to the server that causes the server to write to its own file system, but an Applet does not have a way to write to a file system on a remote machine.

A signed Applet has every right to write to the local file system of the person running the Applet. If you are writing to the "current directory" (rather than an absolute full path), then make sure you know what directory the Applet is running in. Otherwise you may indeed create a file, but not be able to find it!

**EDIT**

[Signed Applet Tutorial](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html)

Comment: Do you know of a good tutorial of how to sign a java applet? And once it is signed, do I have to keep resigning it when i modify it? I use Jcreator btw

Comment: Perhaps, you should invest in an IDE. They are free. Because to my knowledge you cannot sign applets in JCreator. Most people put these into `jar` files and sign them and embed them on their sites.

Comment: I edited in tutorial at bottom of answer @user3794162